# How can I access xampp vhosts on HOST OS (Ubuntu) from Guest OS (Windows 10)?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache2, xampp

I have a machine running `Ubuntu` on host and `Windows10` as Guest running using `VirtualBox`.

I have also setup the vhost say `http://site.local` which is working fine. Now I would like to be able to access this site from Guest.

I can access the HOST `PHPMyadmin` from Guest OS without problems, however, I am unable to access the actual site from Guest

```
(http://site.local)
```

Could anyone help with it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working myself.

I just had to add entry in guest's `hosts` file. So I added

`10.0.2.2 site.local`

in the Windows 10's hosts file which is located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`